# make .ssh/id_rsa read key from yubikey

Tags: ssh, yubikey

I have my [ssh keys within a yubikey](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide), I use `gpg-agent.conf` with something like this:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl 60
max-cache-ttl 120
```

This helps me to `ssh` into any host without having the private key in a file like `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

But in some cases, like when using tools like [ssh-vault](https://ssh-vault.com/), [ansible-vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html), etc, they need to read the key on file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` therefore wondering if there is a way to call the `gpg-agent` to retrieve the key when trying to read from the `~/.ss/id_rsa`, or other ways to retrieve the private keys.

Comment: Wouldn’t that defeat the purpose of storing the keys on a hardware token? Why can these programs not use an SSH agent?

Comment: True, indeed I think the point here is implementing the `agent-support`, but if I am right there is no way to extract the private key from the agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the private key out of a yubikey. This is by design for security reasons.

The way to go with this is to use ssh-agents instead. If they are able to use ssh-agent it is very easy to add your yubikey to it. For OpenSSH its just:

```
ssh-add -s <your-pkcs11.so>
```

Then you can just point you software towards the SSH agent.